# How to register .otf font in reportlab python

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, reportlab

I am working on `reportlab` in python and want to use `Avenir` font I have this font of `OTF` type and There is class `TTFont` in reportlab but i want to use .otf font how to use it

```py
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Avenir", avenir_font_path)) #this only work with .ttfont
```

all your suggestions would be highly appreciated.